# lock application on wrong password entry (c/c++)

Tags: c++, authentication

I want to block user (for 5 mins) from accessing particular Windows based application (C/C++) if incorrect password is entered for 3 times. Do i need to maintain a log file at system level  or is there any way of maintaining some parameter for timer check(e.g. in Cookies)??

Comment: Cookies exist in web apps. It appears that you're describing a local Win32 application.

Comment: yes it is local win 32 application. can i maintain some temp file like cookies? or is there some other good way of doing it? any examples will be very helpful

Comment: Registry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724871(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There are a million ways you could do this. Pretty much every single one of them can be easily defeated (including registry, temp file, in-memory timer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonathan says in a comment, any scheme is usually pretty easy to bypass if the code (application) is only running locally. If there is at least some component running on a server that is reasonably protected, you have a much better chance.

For a "local only scheme", the simplest method is:

```
int count = 0;
for(;;)
{ 
    ask_password();
    if (password == expected_password)
        break;
    count++;
    if (count == 3)
    {
       Sleep(300000);    // 5 minutes = 300000 ms. 
       count = 0;
    }  
}
```

Of course, this just requires the user to close the application and start it again to bypass the timeout. To avoid that "helping", you have to store the "count" in some sort of external storage (registry key is probably the easiest), along with the timestamp of when the last failure was. However, unless you at the very least split your application into a server process that runs with raised privileges (this also means that a "normal user" can't install the application, only someone with admin rights), the user can also alter the registry to bypass the password sleep quite easily.

Of course, a simple but relatively effective way to prevent the "sleep on third bad password" is to sleep for a couple of seconds for each bad attempt. That will make it pretty hard to machine-crack the password, since it now takes two seconds every time it's a bad attempt, rather than the "almost instant" of a typical password comparison.

What you obviously have to ask yourself is how much value there is in doing all this, compared to the risk of someone trying to break into the application. What is it that you are protecting, what is the value of someone breaking in? How difficult is it to bypass the password altogether (for example binary patching over the password check)? How are passwords/usernames stored on the system (can someone with sufficient skill just decode the passwords from a file?)

There is probably no such thing as unbreakable applications/password systems. It's just a matter of how hard you make it vs. the value for someone to break it - if the value is high and you have the right people working on breaking it, it can be broken, no matter how well protected it is. If nothing else works, some blackmail, torture or such on someone that knows the password would probably work... Of course, most people won't do that to find your Facebook or SO password. But if you work for an international bank, there needs to be more than a username/password to protect the entire contents of the bank from being siphoned off...

Comment: very nice explanation!! that solves one portion. I want to know one more thing, if counter is in registry then that will simply block the application for specified time duration... Is it possible to limit the locking restriction to particular instance?? e.g. if i have two running instances of same application. I want to limit the usage of instance/file on which password is entered wrong but other instance should work normally. how can i store the information for particular instance in registry?? on basis of process ID??? some script can be written??

Comment: The point of using the registry is to prevent a NEW instance of the process from bypassing the lockout - in other words, if "User1" tries to log in, fails three times and then closes the application, "User1" should not be able to log in again within 5 minutes, right? No matter which instance of application is used. So somehow you'd need to store the user and time of last unsuccessful login, and the number of failed login attempts. But of course, if you do that, you will still have the problem that if someone knows a number of users, it's still possible to try lots of user/password combos.

Comment: Of course, another point to consider: If you put "LastLoginAttemptUserName" in the registry, it becomes pretty obvious. Likewise using the username in the registry (Just need to call the user "PangalacticGargleBlaster" and search the registry to find where it's stored). So keys and values need to be encrypted. Of course, if it's a standalone application, your encryption key would be in the code, so someone will be able to figure it out. Whether they will spend the effort depends on what you are trying to protect...